# SQL Running Total Grouped By Limit

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to determine how to group records together based the cumulative total of the Qty column so that the group size doesn't exceed 50. The desired group is given in the group column with sample data below.

Is there a way to accomplish this in SQL (specifically SQL Server 2012)?

Thank you for any assistance.

```
ID      Qty     Group
1       10      1
2       20      1
3       30      2  <- 60 greater than 50 so new group
4       40      3
5       2       3
6       3       3
7       10      4
8       25      4
9       15      4
10      5       5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CTE to achieve the goal.

If one of the item exceeds Qty 50, a group still assign for it

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE (ID int identity(1,1) primary key, Qty int)
INSERT @Data VALUES (10), (20), (30), (40), (2), (3), (10), (25), (15), (5)

;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT ID, Qty, 1 AS [Group], Qty AS RunningTotal FROM @Data WHERE ID = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT data.ID, data.Qty, 
        -- The group limits to 50 Qty
        CASE WHEN cte.RunningTotal + data.Qty > 50 THEN cte.[Group] + 1 ELSE cte.[Group] END, 
        -- Reset the running total for each new group
        data.Qty + CASE WHEN cte.RunningTotal + data.Qty > 50 THEN 0 ELSE cte.RunningTotal END
    FROM @Data data INNER JOIN cte ON data.ID = cte.ID + 1
)
SELECT ID, Qty, [Group] FROM cte
```

Comment: This solution does work, however if the sample data contains more rows the recursion will exceed the limit. Is there a non-recursive solution?

Answer (score 0):

The following query gives you most of what you want.  One more self-join of the result would compute the group sizes:

```
select a.ID, G, sum(b.Qty) as Total
from (
    select max(ID) as ID, G
    from (
        select a.ID, sum(b.Qty) / 50 as G 
        from T as a join T as b
        where a.ID >= b.ID
        group by a.ID
    ) as A
    group by G
) as a join T as b
where a.ID >= b.ID
group by a.ID

ID          G           Total 
----------  ----------  ----------
2           0           30        
3           1           60        
8           2           140       
10          3           160
```

The two important tricks:

1. Use a self-join with an inequality to get running totals
2. Use integer division to calculate group numbers.

I discuss this and other techniques on my [canonical SQL](http://www.schemamania.org/sql/) page.

Comment: I don't think the group numbers here are what the OP is looking for . For eg.  for ID 4  - 40 in the example this will return group number as 2 , while it should be 3 because   once a group is exhausted it needs to be padded to 50 so new group begins after the padded total.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a stored procedure for this.

If you have Group column in your database then you have to take care about it while inserting a new record by fetching the max Group value and its sum of Qty column otherwise if you want Group column as computed in select statement then you have to code stored procedure accordingly.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question